# macOS: Schedule a reboot, once, in a separate session

Tags: bash, macos

I need to reboot a macOS system via a script, but the script needs to exit before the reboot has commenced.
This is difficult because `shutdown`, if given a timeout (*eg* `shutdown +1`), will *stay open* until such time as it must do its job. That's no good -- the command to issue the shutdown needs to come and go, and the script containing the commands must conclude with an exit code *before the shutdown/reboot has elapsed*.

`at` is out. Not only does `sudo shutdown -r now | at now + 1 minute` reboot the system immediately (helpful!) but using this complicated workaround and then closing the terminal results in no reboot at the stated time:

```
at now + 1 minute <<END
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to restart'
END
```

(I'm using an alternate reboot command here; the behaviour is the same). It would appear that `at` needs to be kept alive in order to schedule its duties, or at least the terminal session within which `at` is running must, which again precludes the concept of scripting such a duty. The script needs to run from start to EOF and conclude with an exit code, which is then to be sent back to a central server, and all this needs to happen before the device has begun to reboot itself.

`launchd` and `cron` both seem more geared towards scheduling tasks to happen at regular intervals, which isn't what I'm looking for. This is an ad-hoc reboot performed with a minute's notice so the endpoint can save their work, not a regular task.

Is there a way to accomplish this or is macOS simply not capable of handling such a complex request (rebooting)?

Comment: Does your script exit properly if you run `shutdown` in the background? E.g. `shutdown -h +1 &`

Comment: Let me try and I'll get back to you.

Comment: The shutdown keeps the shell open. There is no conclusion of the script, so there is no exit code.

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I try this on my machine I get an exit code that I can check with $?. The trick may be that the output masks the shell prompt. Try typing any command after you run your script.

Comment: In fact, I can check the exit code even if I don't explicitly run `shutdown` in the background.

Comment: I think I just don't understand how the software running the command works. It's less about needing an exit code, that was just how I rendered it in the post for the sake of convenience. The shell itself needs to conclude and exit. I suppose `shutdown` is running in memory so it doesn't consider anything to have concluded yet? Either way, it doesn't work alas.

Comment: When you say "shell", are you referring to the Terminal emulator's window? Are you saying you want the window to close, or do you mean something else?

Comment: My apologies for not knowing the nomenclature clearly enough. In Windows, you run a script and it is considered "finished" when both cmd.exe/powershell.exe and the programs it has spawned have stopped running. Whatever the equivalent is for macOS.